# Can't read ZonedDateTime in excel template using JXLS lib

Tags: java, excel, spring, jxls

I have POJO with ZomedDateTime object:

```
public class Pojo {
  private ZonedDateTime date;
}
```

I use jxls lib to bound template with my pojo:

```
Pojo pojo = getFilledPojo;
context.putVar("pojo", pojo);
```

I want to show this date in me excel template. I use next expression for that:

```
${pojo.date.toInstant()}
```

I see the empty cell in the exported template.
Do you have ane ideas how to fix that? 
I cant use Date and send timestamp to calculate it in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not possible yet. I used`$[DATE(${pojo.date.year},${pojo.date.monthValue},${pojo.date.dayOfMonth})]`
Hope it will be helpful.